# How to hide footer in RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I want to add footer with empty layout to the bottom of the recyclerView which will show up only if certain View is visible on screen(In my case FabButton). FabButton is overlapping my last RecyclerView item, so I want to add empty Footer to the bottom of the recyclerview if this FabButton is visible.

ViewHolder inside Adapter for Footer:

```
inner class FooterViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

Inside onBindViewHolder:

```
... ViewHolder above is for items.
else if(holder is FooterViewHolder){
            if (parentFragment.isFabButtonVisible()){
                holder.itemView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                holder.itemView.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
```

This part of the code is working(also else branch is executed correctly), but my footer view is permanently visible on screen. Even if i add only `View.GONE` it is still visible.

XML for Parent Activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/splash_white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        >

        <com.app.TabLayoutEntity.CustomViewPager
            android:id="@+id/fragmentViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@color/splash_white"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-2dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/fabButton"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/fab_gradient"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:shape="oval"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_fab" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment XML(Inside ViewPager):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/itemRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/recyclerview_corners"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check the below answer if it works for you!

Answer (score 3):

If You just wanna avoid overlapping of last item and Fab then you should do this below simple change in xml on `recyclerview` and parent layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingBottom="paddingindp"/>// for example You can add 100dp and test
```

and on parent layout add this below line

```
android:clipToPadding="true"
```

this will make your `recyclerview` scroll over that Fab and its doesnt require to add Footer view

Hope this work for your requirement.

Comment: This solution will be problematic for me. I have ViewPagerAdapter holding multiple Fragments. Inside these Fragments is recyclerView. And I don't know how to set padding for each fragment's recyclerView. I've tried to get current visible fragment with method viewPagerAdapter.getItem(viewPager.currentItem) but this will create new instance of that fragment, so recyclerView is not initialized there. -> I cant change it's padding yet.

Comment: if You can post your xml skeleton here so it will easy to help you.@martin1337

Comment: It's up there now.

Comment: Yes, I See it, above code will work in this cases as i have myself has used in such scenario so make the changes and let me know if any issues with that.@martin1337

Comment: It will work, but I have to change this padding programatically depends on fabButton visibility. If visibility is gone = padding = 0dp else padding = 60dp. And I have to set this padding for every fragment in that viewPager.

Comment: And ... i don't know how to do that. I've added setPaddingForEachFragment() method inside my custom ViewPager. It will iterate over fragments and call method setRecyclerViewPadding(visibilityState). Problem is, that this will cause exception: recyclerView has not been initialized.

Comment: If you have method which tells your fab visibility in your main activity then you can access that method in your fragments and can simply apply padding on recyclerview mRecyclerView!!.setPadding(0,0,0,0), hope this way can work for you

Comment: This is what I'm doing. I have setFabVisibility() method inside my parent activity. I will change visibility and call viewPagerAdapter.setVisibilityPadding(fabButton.visibility). This will iterate all of my fragments inside ViewPagerAdapter and call fragmentArray[index].setRecyclerViewPadding(). Which will set padding of RecylerView inside Fragment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180984/discussion-between-shishram-and-martin1337).

Answer (score 2):

You can add your condition in `getItemCount()` method since you need to increase your list size if you add footer

Like,

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
   if (parentFragment.isFabButtonVisible()){
          return mModels.size + 1
   } else {
          return mModels.size
   }
}
```

Comment: this will create problems and have to write more code if pagination is applied on the same!